# Making a low pass filter for irregular samples

Tags: image-processing, filters, filter-design, sampling, lowpass-filter

We are interested in reconstructing the red channel of a scene.

The red channel is slowly varying.

Unfortunately the camera does not have a Bayer sensor, and the red samples are irregularly spaced over the grid: [image: bayer vs xtrans]

How do you design a 2D low-pass filter (convolution kernel) that:

- only depends on the samples of red that you have
- has as close to constant frequency response as possible?

I was thinking of something along the lines of solving an optimization problem relating to the NDFT. Would this idea work? :

> Take the NDFT of the red components we have. Then in continuous space, form the sum of all the sinusoids from the frequency information in the NDFT. Re-sample the function along the whole grid.

Comment: Have you considered interpolation schemes such as [Kriging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kriging#Linear_estimation)? You can weight the estimates with their distance from the known pixel values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realize that this is not a filter, but I do not believe any filter will give you a reasonable result given the strange sample locations. This seems to be borne out by several references on the web. [This one](http://chromasoft.blogspot.com/2012/05/demosaicing-fuji-x-pro1-and-its-x-trans.html) for example and [this PDF one](http://www.sersc.org/journals/IJCA/vol7_no2/35.pdf).

I suggest something something [along these lines](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/30225/80), using [projections onto convex sets (POCS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projections_onto_convex_sets).

**Algorithm Descroption**

Assume that the known red pixel values $R_i$ are at $(x_i,y_i)$ so that your start red image is:
$$
I_{\tt red}(x,y) = \sum_{i=1}^N R_i \delta(x-x_i, y-y_i)
$$

Set $k=0$, and initialize your estimate of the fully sampled red image with $I_{\tt red}(x,y)$:
$$
\hat{I}^k_{\tt red}(x,y) = I_{\tt red}(x,y).
$$

Take the 2D FFT of $\hat{I}^k_{\tt red}$:
$$
F_{\tt red}(n,m) = {\tt FFT}\{\hat{I}^k_{\tt red}(x,y)\}
$$
Because the red channel is slowly varying, remove all frequencies above a cutoff:
$$
F^{lp}_{\tt red}(n,m) = F_{\tt red}(n,m) L(n,m)
$$
where $L$ is a low pass mask.

Form the inverse FFT to get $\hat{I}^{k+1}_{\tt red}(x,y)$
$$
\hat{I}^{k+1}_{\tt red}(x,y) = {\tt FFT}^{-1}\{F^{lp}_{\tt red}(n,m)\}
$$

Set the known pixels of $\hat{I}^{k+1}_{\tt red}(x,y)$ from $I_{\tt red}(x,y)$.

If the difference between $\hat{I}^{k+1}_{\tt red}(x,y)$ and $\hat{I}^{k}_{\tt red}(x,y)$ is small enough, stop, otherwise reiterate with $k=k+1$.

**Results**

An example run with just a $6 \times 6$ matrix is below. The left image shows the original pixels. The right image shows the POCS version.  The red dots show the original pixel locations in both images.

[image]

**Different Initial Conditions**

I tried setting the initial image to

```
Ired <- array(100000,c(ImageSize, ImageSize))
```

and

```
Ired <- array(128,c(ImageSize, ImageSize))
```

and the results are below, so I do not believe the initial values for the unknown pixels matter.

The plot scales the greyscale values, which is why the 100,000 example looks wrong in the left-hand plot.

[image: For initial values of 100,000]

[image: For initial values of 128]

---

**R Code Below**

```
# 32018
# Non-Bayer 2D interpolation

# Model pixels as:
# P(x,y) = (a_0 + a_1 * x + a_2 * x^2) * (b_0 + b_1 * y + b_2 * y^2)
#        = [a_0 a_1 a_2 b_0 b_1 b_2] * [1 x x^2 1 y y^2]^T 
# And so we need to find the a_i and b_i from specific pixel and coordinate values.
#
# install.packages('ptw')

require(ptw)

pad <- function(x,N)
{
  p1 <- ptw::padzeros(x,N,side="right")
  p2 <- t(ptw::padzeros(t(p1),N,side="right"))

  return(p2)
}

Npoints <- 8
xy <- array(c(c(1,1), c(1,5), c(2,3), c(3,6), c(4,2), c(4,4), c(5,6), c(6,3)), c(2,Npoints))
xy_norm <- (xy - min(xy))/(max(xy) - min(xy))
Pxy <- array(runif(N, 0, 255), c(1,Npoints))

ImageSize <- max(xy)

Ired <- array(0,c(ImageSize, ImageSize))

for (idx in 1:Npoints)
{
  Ired[xy[1,idx], xy[2,idx]] = Pxy[idx]
}

Ihatred <-array(0,c(ImageSize,ImageSize))
Ihatred2 <- Ired
count <- 0

while (sum(abs(Ihatred - Ihatred2)) > 1)
{
  Ihatred <- Ihatred2

  Fred <- fft(pad(Ihatred, 2*ImageSize))

  Fredsize <- dim(Fred)[1]
  cutoff1 <- Fredsize / 8
  cutoff2 <- 7 * Fredsize / 8

  Fred[4:16,] <- 0
  Fred[,4:16] <- 0

  IFred <- fft(Fred, inverse=TRUE) / Fredsize / Fredsize

  Ihatred2 <- Re(IFred[1:ImageSize, 1:ImageSize])

  for (idx in 1:Npoints)
  {
    Ihatred2[xy[1,idx], xy[2,idx]] = Pxy[idx]
  }

  count <- count + 1  
  if (count > 100)
  {
    break
  }  
}


par(mfrow=c(1,2))
image(Ired, col= grey(seq(0, 1, length = 256)))
for (idx in 1:Npoints)
{
  points(xy_norm[1,idx] , xy_norm[2,idx] , col="red", lwd=5)
}
title('Original with only known red pixels')
image(Ihatred2, col= grey(seq(0, 1, length = 256)))
title('POCS solution')
for (idx in 1:Npoints)
{
  points(xy_norm[1,idx] , xy_norm[2,idx] , col="red", lwd=5)
}
```

Comment: Won't the initial image being mostly black influence what it converges to?

Comment: @enthdegree : I do not believe it should matter, and I have added two examples. One has the unknown pixels set to 100,000 and the other has them set to 128. Both converge to the same image.