# Is there a $z$-transform like for variable sampling rate signals?

Tags: filter-design, z-transform, filtering

I'm working with signals with variable sampling rate (the time space between samples is not constant). I know the delay between samples but I don't wont to interpolate the signal.

Is there a way to design a filter in $z$ domain and filter a signal with variable sampling rate without interpolation?

Comment: when you say variable sample rate, do you mean multiple data rates within a system, sample rates that change on the fly, or something else?

Comment: I mean that the space between samples is not constant

Comment: A continuous time State Space system doesn’t necessarily require constant sample intervals but you have to solve a set matrix differential equations at each time step, which can be more involved than interpolation

Comment: Have you documentation about it?

Comment: If you happen to have chapter 7 of BP Lathi's , Signal, Systems, and Control, 1974, there is a good discussion.  I'll look around around if I can find something more available.  There is also something called the Advanced Z transform https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Z-transform that is peripherally relevant,

Answer (score 2):

Since the powers in the $z$-transform relate to delays or lags, in the philosophy of Laurent series, I would like to mention [Puiseux series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puiseux_series), a generalization of power series with negative and fractional exponents, or the [Hahn (or Hahn–Mal'cev–Neumann) series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn_series), with even more flexibility in the  exponents. However, their use in signal processing remains quite shallow to me yet.

I suspect than rational exponents could be still tractable. Indeed, they are used on multiband ($M$-band) filterbanks, where you can spot weirdities like $X(z^{1/2})$ or $X(z^{1/M})$, but most of them are based only on rationals with $M^p$ denominators. 
More generic powers (irrational) could be *way* more involved. The only mentions of Puiseux series I have found on IEEE Xlore are in the domain of control and automation (definitely not my cup of tea).

Comment: Yes, I've only ever seen methods based on doing the interpolation, [generally based on POCS (projections onto convex sets) techniques](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.296.5976&rep=rep1&type=pdf). I do wonder if a POCS technique NOT interpolating onto a uniform grid might work, but I haven't explored that. I played with a POCS technique [here on this site](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/30219/random-sampling-vs-uniform-sampling/30225#30225)

Comment: Good source. I however wonder whether this can be called "$z$-transform like, as it seems to remains "very Fourier". As there is a  literature on "fllter-design" with non-uniform sampling, I may have focused on the "$z$-transform term, for which I haven't seen DSP mention of Puiseux or Hahn